# Find all positive integers n, such that $n2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: number-theory

Find all positive integers $n$, such that $n2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$

I was trying to solve with normal Diophantine equation but couldn't get and don't know much about modular arithmetic . Please help me out in this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Ok thanks for informing I didn't knew it will take care in future

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that the edit of the question was accurate.

Comment: I have rolled back the edits, as they appear to have drastically changed the meaning. If I have erred in so doing, please let me know.  Assuming that the original form $n2^n+1$ is correct, then just test $n\in \{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ until you spot the pattern.  It does not take too long.

Comment: Now the question is correct

Comment: Please tell how to solve now

Comment: The simplest uses (elementary) congruences mod. $3$. Note there are only $3$ congruence classes $0,1$ and $2\equiv -1$.

Comment: Please tell as I am unable to solve

Comment: Bernard can you answer in answer section please as in comment section I can't read properly

Comment: I gave you a suggestion, why not follow it?  Just check for small $n$ until you see the pattern.  Knowing the result will make it a lot easier to prove.

Comment: It is probably determined modulo 6

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A021823

Comment: Ok Lulu I will try

Comment: If you are interested, I have added [here][1] a solution which does not use modular arithmetic.


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355821/divisibility-of-n-cdot2n1-by-3/3774524#3774524